# Need sample AXML for Android Card content blocks

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, xamarin, android-cardview

Android has a list of [UX/UI samples here](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/cards.html#cards-actions) and I'm looking for any example AXAML layouts that would match those UX/UI illustrations.

Does any such layout library exist? I would prefer to simply copy and paste UI code, since that isn't my expertise.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of a direct one to one library as that is Google's design spec for all platforms Google runs vs. an actual implementation on a specific device/browser (android being just one).

You tagged your question with Xamarin, but asked about AXAML(?)/AXML. If you are looking for AXML examples of Android cards (vs. Tamarin's Form XAML), I would load up the Android Studio and browse the Github based googlesamples. You could use github directly, but with AS you have a AXML GUI designer so you can edit cards visually (and in text mode) and then copy the AXML over to Xamarin to load the GUI of your Android app via a resource.

Starting with the CardView sample would be your best bet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
 Copyright 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 You may obtain a copy of the License at
     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 limitations under the License.
-->
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                  android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                  android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                  android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        >
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="100dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/cardview_initial_background"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_large"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_large"
            >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
                android:text="@string/cardview_contents"
                />
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_large"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/seekbar_label_length"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/cardview_radius_seekbar_text"
                />
            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/cardview_radius_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="@dimen/seekbar_label_length"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/cardview_elevation_seekbar_text"
                />
            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/cardview_elevation_seekbar"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="@dimen/margin_medium"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```